# Insert ASCII Control Characters via TinyMCE?

Tags: html, web, tinymce, ascii

Is it possible to insert ASCII Control Characters into a WYSIWYG editor like TinyMCE?

When you copy a content using <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> from a file opened in Notepad that has `SOH` in it added using HEX Editor, would that `SOH` be retained in the clipboard?

From what I understand, keyboards usually don't have a key for control characters like `SOH` (though `CR`, `DEL` etc have keys). If it exists also shouldn't it to do some action and not create a Textual Content?

I am debugging an issue where we see how `SOH` in our Database and if there is a possiblity that Web Forms especially TinyMCE can get this from the end user.

One theory could be that my MSSQL Database is ISO Latin. So perhaps it has accepted some unicode content which has one of the bytes as `\x01` that gets interperted as `SOH`?

Comment: Ultimately somebody could have made a raw HTTP request to your server including any arbitrary byte they want…

Comment: HTTP requests happen via Web Service calls to our system. But we are not checking any possibility directly from the Browser?

Comment: Another alternative is probably a unicode content mis-read as a ASCII Control Character?

Comment: You want to ensure that your database and your application are using the same encoding.  Your web application and TinyMCE are almost certainly using UTF-8 and if your database is using a different encoding this can lead to issues.  ISO Latin is not UTF-8 so for some characters they could be mis-encoded when stored and retrieved from the database.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelFromin. Is there a possibility of Control Characters going in from Copy-Paste in any scenario say paste from Notepad (Text) or Browser (HTML)? I really can't imagine how that is possible! I created a Notepad with `SOH` for example. I can understand the UTF-8 vs ISO Latin scenario but in that case I need to see which unicode chracter can have `SOH` i.e `\x01` as one of the byte sequence - there could be?

Comment: Encoding issues can lead to all sorts of mangled content once you encode/decode across multiple character sets.  I have never seen the SOH character you reference personally so I can't speak to that particular character.